# Enum Singleton Double Creation

Tags: java, android, enums, singleton, race-condition

In my Android application I have a singleton class that looks like this:

```
public enum AudioManager {
   INSTANCE;

   private final Object mLockLoad = new Object();
   private final Object mSPLockLoad = new Object();

   public void loadFiles(final Context context, final Locale locale) {
       synchronized (mLockLoad) {
          //Load SoundPool and other stuff

         Thread thread = new Thread() {
             @Override
             public void run() {
                 synchronized (mSPLockLoad) {
                     loadAllSounds(context);
                     mSPLockLoad.notify();
                 }
             }
         };
         thread.start();
     }
 }
```

And then from an Activity class I use this to call it:

```
public static void loadAudioFiles(final Context context, final Locale locale) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {    
            AudioManager.INSTANCE.loadFiles(
                                 context.getApplicationContext(),
                                 locale);
        }
    }, "AudioManagerInitializeThread").start();
}
```

At some point a race condition happens and `loadFiles()` is called twice. Where could the problem be?
If I get the instance on the main UI thread would I avoid it:

```
public static void loadAudioFiles(final Context context, final Locale locale) {
    AudioManager manager = AudioManager.INSTANCE;
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {    
            manager.loadFiles(context.getApplicationContext(), locale);
        }
    }, "AudioManagerInitializeThread").start();
}
```

Comment: You are not remembering if `loadAllSounds` was called - is it an error?

Comment: Also `mLockLoad` seems redundant

Comment: I have a loadedDone flag that I se to true after `loadAllSound()` but I only use it when I play sounds. I also use `mLockLoad` when I release the resources.

Comment: `mLockLoad` is not being held inside `loadAllSounds` since it's called outside the thread

Comment: @AntonMalyshev what do you suggest?

Comment: @IulianGheorghita, use standardized solutions for this, don't start threads which start a thread that starts a thread. Use consistent threading model which you understand. Lastly, look at what Google recommends doing for tasks such as these.

Comment: If you call this `loadFiles` method twice, it would be called twice regardless of how many locks you put in there. Locks meant to order calls, not disable them.

Comment: Would adding a `isLoading` flag help me here?

Comment: I only need to to load the audio files once.